# SQL deadlock on multithreaded massive delete query and bulk insert batches

Tags: mysql, sql, multithreading, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I have a batch in .NET that reads a lot of files and stores their content into a single MySQL InnoDB table with the following structure:

```
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `Source` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
   `Period` char(1) NOT NULL,
   `idItem` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `StartDate` datetime NOT NULL,
   `MoreData` varchar(255)
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `Combination` (`Source`,`Period`,`idItem`,`StartDate`),
```

Where

- idItem is a foreign key
- Source, Period, and idItem are indices
- Combination is a unique index.

To perform the table update, I then have a transaction with two steps:

1. Delete all old rows that have a StartDate within the time interval of my newer dataset.
2. Insert new rows with a single INSERT statement (up to 10,000 rows).

   START TRANSACTION;

   DELETE FROM data WHERE Source = @Source AND Period = @Period AND idItem = @idItem AND StartDate >= @FirstDate AND StartDate <= @LastDate;

   INSERT INTO data(..,..,..,..) VALUES(..,..,..,..)(..,..,..,..)(..,..,..,..)(..,..,..,..);

   COMMIT;

The problem is that when running this from multiple threads (works fine with 1 thread, breaks with 2 or more threads) at the same time, even if each thread can only update a different set of (*Source,Period,idItem*) (no overlapping), I get a 1213 exception: **Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting**.

This problem is very similar to the one described here: [SQL deadlock on delete then bulk insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496005/sql-deadlock-on-delete-then-bulk-insert)

What would you suggest to prevent this kind of deadlock? I have tried everything suggested [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html) but with no convincing results. Thanks!

Annex:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
110911 12:00:45
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 5167, ACTIVE 3 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 4 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 225, query id 86933 192.168.1.1 root updating
DELETE FROM data WHERE Source = ''mysource'' AND Period = ''D'' AND idItem = 17 AND StartDate >= ''2009-07-22 00:00:00'' AND StartDate <= ''2011-08-29 00:00:00'' ORDER BY StartDate
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 61 page no 389 n bits 344 index `SourcePeriodItemStartDate` of table `crdb`.`data` trx id 5167 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 229 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000011; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 80001245bc591c80; asc    E Y  ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015b9fd; asc     ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 5163, ACTIVE 8 sec inserting, thread declared inside InnoDB 198
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
33 lock struct(s), heap size 6960, 2419 row lock(s), undo log entries 1625
MySQL thread id 224, query id 86924 192.168.1.1 root update
insert data(...)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 61 page no 389 n bits 344 index `SourcePeriodItemStartDate` of table `crdb`.`data` trx id 5163 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124821527f80; asc    H!R  ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c121; asc    !;;

Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800012482161c1c0; asc    H!a  ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c122; asc    ";;

Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124821710400; asc    H!q  ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c123; asc    #;;

Record lock, heap no 5 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 80001248219ecac0; asc    H!   ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c124; asc    $;;

Record lock, heap no 6 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124821ae0d00; asc    H!   ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c125; asc    %;;

Record lock, heap no 7 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124821bd4f40; asc    H! O@;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c126; asc    &;;

Record lock, heap no 8 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124821cc9180; asc    H!   ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c127; asc    '';;

Record lock, heap no 9 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124821dbd3c0; asc    H!   ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c128; asc    (;;

Record lock, heap no 10 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124822099a80; asc    H"   ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c129; asc    );;

Record lock, heap no 11 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800012482218dcc0; asc    H"   ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c12a; asc    *;;

Record lock, heap no 12 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124822281f00; asc    H"(  ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c12b; asc    +;;

Record lock, heap no 13 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124822376140; asc    H"7a@;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c12c; asc    ,;;

Record lock, heap no 14 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800012482246a380; asc    H"F  ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c12d; asc    -;;

Record lock, heap no 15 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124822746a40; asc    H"tj@;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c12e; asc    .;;

Record lock, heap no 16 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800012482283ac80; asc    H"   ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c12f; asc    /;;

Record lock, heap no 17 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800012482292eec0; asc    H"   ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c130; asc    0;;

Record lock, heap no 18 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124822a23100; asc    H" 1 ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c131; asc    1;;

Record lock, heap no 19 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124822b17340; asc    H" s@;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c132; asc    2;;

Record lock, heap no 20 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124826fc1540; asc    H&  @;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c133; asc    3;;

Record lock, heap no 21 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 80001248270b5780; asc    H'' W ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c134; asc    4;;

Record lock, heap no 22 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 80001248271a99c0; asc    H''   ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c135; asc    5;;

Record lock, heap no 23 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800012482729dc00; asc    H'')  ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c136; asc    6;;

Record lock, heap no 24 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124827391e40; asc    H''9 @;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c137; asc    7;;

Record lock, heap no 25 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800012482766e500; asc    H''f  ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c138; asc    8;;

Record lock, heap no 26 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124827762740; asc    H''v''@;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c139; asc    9;;

Record lock, heap no 27 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124827856980; asc    H'' i ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c13a; asc    :;;

Record lock, heap no 28 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800012482794abc0; asc    H''   ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c13b; asc    ;;;

Record lock, heap no 29 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124827a3ee00; asc    H''   ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c13c; asc    <;;

Record lock, heap no 30 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124827d1b4c0; asc    H''   ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c13d; asc    =;;

Record lock, heap no 31 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124827e0f700; asc    H''   ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c13e; asc    >;;

Record lock, heap no 32 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124827f03940; asc    H'' 9@;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c13f; asc    ?;;

Record lock, heap no 33 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124827ff7b80; asc    H'' { ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c140; asc    @;;

Record lock, heap no 34 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 80001248280ebdc0; asc    H(   ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c141; asc    A;;

Record lock, heap no 35 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 80001248283c8480; asc    H(<  ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c142; asc    B;;

Record lock, heap no 36 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 80001248284bc6c0; asc    H(K  ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c143; asc    C;;

Record lock, heap no 37 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 80001248285b0900; asc    H([  ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c144; asc    D;;

Record lock, heap no 38 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124828798d80; asc    H(y  ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c145; asc    E;;

Record lock, heap no 39 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124828a75440; asc    H( T@;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c146; asc    F;;

Record lock, heap no 40 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000124828b69680; asc    H(   ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c147; asc    G;;

Record lock, heap no 41 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800012482cf1f640; asc    H,  @;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c148; asc    H;;

Record lock, heap no 42 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800012482d013880; asc    H- 8 ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c149; asc    I;;

Record lock, heap no 43 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800012482d107ac0; asc    H- z ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c14a; asc    J;;

Record lock, heap no 44 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800012482d3e4180; asc    H->A ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c14b; asc    K;;

Record lock, heap no 45 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800012482d4d83c0; asc    H-M  ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c14c; asc    L;;

Record lock, heap no 46 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800012482d5cc600; asc    H-\  ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c14d; asc    M;;

Record lock, heap no 47 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800012482d6c0840; asc    H-l @;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c14e; asc    N;;

Record lock, heap no 48 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800012482d7b4a80; asc    H-{J ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c14f; asc    O;;

Record lock, heap no 49 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800012482da91140; asc    H-  @;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c150; asc    P;;

Record lock, heap no 50 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800012482db85380; asc    H- S ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c151; asc    Q;;

Record lock, heap no 51 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000010; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800012482dc795c0; asc    H-   ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015c152; asc    R;;

 (around 250 more record locks like this)

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 61 page no 389 n bits 544 index `SourcePeriodItemStartDate` of table `crdb`.`data` trx id 5163 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 229 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 2; hex 4242; asc mysource;;
 1: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000011; asc     ;;
 3: len 8; hex 80001245bc591c80; asc    E Y  ;;
 4: len 4; hex 8015b9fd; asc     ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Comment: Did you solved this problem? I have the same with oracle.

Comment: I don't think I solved this problem in any useful way for others (it was a long time ago though).

Answer (score 0):

Add `ORDER BY StartDate` to the delete. (so the rows get locked in a specific order)

Comment: Thanks but it does not seem to help :(, I keep getting the exception (with only 2 threads).

Comment: Why not put the insert into another transaction?

Comment: Splitting into two transactions fails miserably with another exception (with 8 threads):
"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond".

Comment: Moreover, the purpose of having the deletion and insertion in the same transaction would be to intercept conflicting updates to rows within the same (Source,Period,idItem), in case another process (not thread) tried to access the database and do other kinds of modifications. Otherwise it could be possible that once the rows are deleted, it would be no longer possible to insert the new ones because another process had inserted others.
Ideally, I would like to include in the same transaction the two operations plus another that writes into another table to specify characteristics of the dataset.

Comment: If you have pegged the database, it sounds like splitting into two transactions worked wonderfully. If there are other processes running, you probably need to throttle back so that you are taking less than 100%. What is the purpose to all the threads? Four transactions in parellel will not complete faster than 4 serial transactions. Try it with 1, 2, 3, and 4 threads and measure the time to complete. You may find that 2 or 3 is optimal.

Comment: Reducing to 3 threads, it seems to work, but not having transactions may create a data integrity risk... But the most important thing is that there should be no real concurrency here (assuming a (Source,Period,idItem) tuple will only be modified by a single thread), so I wonder why there is a deadlock in the first place.