# Would partitioning prevent database deadlocks, when they are caused by rows that would otherwise be into two partitions?

Tags: mysql, sql, partitioning, database-deadlocks

I am struggling with deadlocks that should not even be, as I am running bulk delete and inserts on mutually exclusive subsets of a table.
Yet deadlocks seem unavoidable when running the queries on multiple threads (each of which accessing data that could be on separate partitions).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379223/sql-deadlock-on-multithreaded-massive-delete-query-and-bulk-insert-batches) for more details on the issue, but I am wondering more generally speaking if partitioning is recommended to deal with deadlocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO partioning would not solve anything. The chain of events for a deadlock situation is basically:

```
T1: get lock L1;
    get lock L2;

T2: get lock L2;
    get lock L1;
```

Deadlock occurs if T1 and t2 are both halfway, each owning one lock.
Nothing will change if the L1 and L2 locks refer to objects in different tables; it is only the ordering of events that causes the deadlock.

Comment: If partitioning makes it so that we have four different locks instead of 2 (which should be the case with manually created tables for each "subset"), then it would work.